# How to measure the capacity of the battery Instantly?

Tags: batteries

How to measure the capacity of various types of batteries instantly? What kind of measuring device should I use to do so?

Comment: Do you mean "Capacity" = how much energy the battery CAN hold, or "State of charge" = how much energy the battery holds at present ?

Comment: For normal batteries probably not possible, but for smart batteries (like those in laptops, mobile phones) all have integrated small control IC, which can provide you information such us design capacity and actual capacity.

Comment: You should be a little more specific, as different batteries have different discharge curves.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not possible to measure or guess the capacity of a battery with a single set of instantaneous measurements, like voltage, current, and temperature.

At best you can tell how much current is going into or out of the battery a what voltage.  However, there is no way to infer capacity from that.  If you can control the load, you can get some idea of the internal resistance, but even that would take at least two measurements separated in time and therefore can not be done instantly.  And, battery voltage and internal resistance does not tell you capacity.

Answer (score 2):

For lead-acid batteries, you can (in theory) measure the [density of the electrolyte](http://www.engineersedge.com/battery/specific_gravity_battery.htm) while it's discharging.

Unfortunately there aren't really any practical sensors to do that automatically. (If you have a large battery, you could use a hydrometer.) Also, it doesn't appear to work accurately during charging (at least according to the link above).

Comment: At best that tells you state of charge, but that still has nothing to do with capacity.

Answer (score 1):

### Lithium Polymer batteries

These batteries, which are now used in almost all consumer mobile applications, have a discharge curve like this:

[image: http://www.powerstream.com/lithuim-ion-charge-voltage.htm]

(Image taken from http://www.powerstream.com/lithuim-ion-charge-voltage.htm)

So, to a certain point, it's possible to determine the charge level of the battery just measuring the voltage; since the relationship is not linear, a look-up table or something similar is used to determine the charge from the voltage measure.

The problem is that with aging, the curve changes, as the battery life vbecome shorter; if the values in the look-up table are not updated with a calibration, they will start to give wrong values. As an example, it might have happened to you that your old cellphone says that the battery is half charge and after a few hours you find it almost completely empty.

Comment: do you have experience in designing charging circuits for these kind of batteries?

Comment: @sandundhammika I've never designed any, but I tested some different charging circuits to check their efficiency. Why do you ask?

Comment: Those curves will look different under a higher or lower load, temperature, etc.  They are not useful as a lookup table.  What you can tell is that if the voltage is above 3.8V then it's mostly charged and below 3.2V it's mostly discharged.  In between, voltage doesn't tell you anything you can rely on.  Look at a 3.7V reading - was the battery just charged to 3.8V, or charged to 4.3V and discharged about halfway?  No way to tell from voltage alone.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this for at least lead-acid batteries is to load it at 100A for about 10 s to see what the voltage will sag to.

It is not at all a perfect way to measure but it gives a good hint about the "life-force" of the battery.

You could do this to other types of batteries as well but some batteries like LI-ion will die and might explore if you discharge them at a too large current so DO NOT try this with random battery types.

Comment: Some Lead-Acid batteries cannot provide 100A. For example a [Yuasa NP1.2-6](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1500696.pdf) has a maximum discharge current of 12A and a short-circuit current of 36A. I'd check battery specs before performing this type of test.

Comment: Well, 100A is for something like a car battery, for a small  lead acid battery something lower but still high for that battery would be better, say 1C.